# Fit content (images, documents, videos) inside iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

I have an MVC project with a View called Index.cshtml. I have a dynamically created iFrame (its HTML is created in a string then appended to the .html() of a div), and its content changes depending on the user selection from a table in another div.

Here's my problem: the content inside the iFrame appears incorrectly. For example, a large image is shown but I need to scroll inside the iframe to view the rest of it. Or, a video is shown but it is small sized (surrounded by a thick black border, not fitted to the iframe). Now I have set the iframe's width and height to be 100% of the parent div. Also, the content of the iframe is dynamic. Meaning: depending on what the user chose from the table, the content could be an **image**, a **video**, or a **document**. That means I have no control over what HTML is generated inside the iframe.

Here's a sample code to help generate my problem:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

    <title>Kitty Cat</title>

</head>

<body style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 18px !important; font-weight: normal">
    <div>
        <div id="MrData" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
            <div id="divData">
                <iframe id="theiframe" src="https://i.imgur.com/0XHcPko.jpg" frameborder="5" style="width:100%; height: 100%" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you run this page, the image of a cat will appear but it will only show the upper left corner of that image. Keep in mind I disabled scrolling because I'm trying to force whatever content to appear fully instead of having to scroll.

How do I make the content inside the div small or big to show up fully in the iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Add this to your  section:

```
<script>
  function resizeIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

> And change your iframe to this:

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="resizeIframe(this)" />
```